# In ckeditor4, the underline style of these "g j p q y" letters is incorrect

Tags: underline, ckeditor4

In the ckeditor4 rich text editor, the underline style of other text is normal, but the style of these "g j p q y" letters is displayed incorrectly. There is a picture showing the result below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbA7I.png)

How can I fix this problem?